# CMake link Release library to Debug target

Tags: c, cmake

I have an imported library named a.lib, which is imported from another project that I don't have its source code.

a.lib is generated with CMake Release mode.

Now, I want to generate target b and link a to by

```
add_executable(b ${SOURCES})
target_include_directories(b ${HEADERS})
target_link_libraries(b PRIVATE a.lib)
```

But target 'b' should contain its symbols in Debug mode so that I can debug it line by line.

How can I link those together?

It seems Cmake does not allow me to link Debug target with Release lib.

Comment: `It seems Cmake does not allow me to link Debug target with Release lib.` Please be more specific. What happens when you do? How does cmake not allow you to do it?

Answer (score 0):

So add debugging flags to the executable.

```
 target_compile_options(b PRIVATE ${CMAKE_C_DEBUG_FLAGS})
```

or maybe `CMAKE_C_DEBUG_FLAGS_INIT` or cancel those flags (like `-g0`) from your library.

And you can always compile your library and your executable in two separate cmake projects and link them then, using a script or `ExternalProject_Add`